# FXCop assembly load failure

Tags: fxcop, sonar-runner, fxcopcmd

Command line:

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Fxcop 10.0\FxCopCmd.exe" /file:XXX.exe /out:fxcop-report.xml /outxsl:none /forceoutput /searchgac /assemblyCompareMode:StrongNameIgnoringVersion /verbose
```

Error from report:

```
   <Type>Microsoft.FxCop.Common.AssemblyLoadException</Type>
   <ExceptionMessage>Could not load XXX.</ExceptionMessage>
   <InnerType>Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.InvalidMetadataException</InnerType>
   <InnerExceptionMessage>The following error was encountered while reading module 'XXX': Security attribute type does not have a default constructor: System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission.</InnerExceptionMessage>
```

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Does module XXX contain any subclasses of CodeAccessPermissionAttribute?  If so, do any of them deviate from the instructions regarding constructors in the "Notes to Inheritors" section at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.codeaccesssecurityattribute.aspx#remarksToggle?

Comment: Long story short, it was from an IKVM generated assembly which was merged (il-merge) into our primary assembly. I think we can avoid running FXCop against the merged assembly.